# determinant of a a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Could Any One Tell Me How To Solve This One?]

I understand that matrix of $T$ will be $6\times 6$ and will consists of $1,0$ but not able to find out what will be the determimant.

Comment: Note the $-x_6$ in the upper left corner of the image of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

If we didn't have the -1 coefficient in the first entry (look carefully at graphic), $T$ would be a permutation of entries, and the determinant of $T$ would be $\pm 1$ accordingly as $T$ is an even or odd permutation (as defined by the number of transpositions needed to write the permutation in a combinatorial/group theory sense).  Throw in the -1 on that row of the matrix representation, and the determinant will still be $\pm 1$, but opposite in sign to what the permutation by itself would give.

Answer (score 2):

Here the space of matrices is viewed as a 6-dimensional space.  The 2 by 3 matrix structure is irrelevant.  Therefore it is preferable to view this map as $T:\mathbb{R}^6\to \mathbb{R}^6$ given by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)\mapsto(x_6,x_4,x_1,x_3,x_5,x_2)$.  Then one immediately recongnizes a permutation matrix.  Hence its determinant is either $1$ or $-1$.  Now all you have to do is determine whether the permutation is even or odd, for example by decomposing it into cycles.

I just noticed the minus sign on $x_6$, so this is not exactly a permutation matrix.  That changes the sign of the determinant to its opposite.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is a permutation of the elements of the base, so its matrix has only one $1$ in every row and every column. The determinant of such matrix equals $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Is the permutation $(1,6,2,4,3)\in S_6$ even or odd? The determinant of the linear operator equals the negative of the sign of this permutation (the sign of the permutation is $1$ if it's even and $-1$ if it's odd). Why?

I hope this helps! (The details are minimal so you might have to think a little bit to understand my answer.)

Comment: $(1,6,2,4,3)=(1,6)(6,2)(2,4)(4,3)(3,1)$ is odd permutation.so determimant will be finally $1$

Comment: @miosaki it will be $(1,3)(1,4)(1,2)(1,6)$ so even permutation

Comment: so the answer will be $-1$ not $+1$

Comment: @miosaki Taxi Driver is correct; the answer is $-1$ rather than $+1$.

Answer (score -1):

I think that for the transformation to be defined, $T$ must be a $2x2$ matrix.After which you will have a system of equations. Then you may solve for the entries of $T$.

Comment: $T$ is not a matrix, it is a linear transformation from the space of real $2\times 3$ matrices (a real six-dimensional vector space) to itself. By choosing a basis for the vector space, we can view $T$ as a $6\times 6$ matrix which, of course, has a determinant.

Comment: The OP is correct that as a map from $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 3}$ to itself, a six dimensional real vector space, a matrix representation of $T$ will be $6\times 6$.